# How to move an element with a certain prefix to another element in vanila javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

In this code, I tried to make the list dynamic, so that when the user creates a new list that begins with a certain symbol, for example (*), the entire list moves to the nearest list that does not contain the symbol (*) and that is dynamically

Example ..

....first code

- one
- two
- *three
- *fore
- *five
- six
- saven
- *aite
- *nine
- ten

.... Then

```
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two
      <ul>
        <li>*three</li>
        <li>*fure</li>
        <li>*five</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>saven
      <ul>
        <li>*aite</li>
        <li>*nane</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>teen</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.